# arrays remove object that's matches with objects from other array

Tags: arrays, node.js

i want to remove objects from if they are  the same value 
for example 
first array (disnicknames)

```
{ '1': { blko: 1 }, '13': { blko: 13 } }
```

second array (nicknames)

```
{ '1': { online: false, stest: 765767, thnick: 'kjjkjkj', userid: 1 },
  '13': { online: false, stest: 87, thnick: 'nnnmm', userid: 13 },'18': { online: true, stest: 56, thnick: 'iiii', userid: 18 }, }
```

i want to remove the object from second array if the userid or the number before object for example

> '13': { bla: bla,...,...,..,}

are one of the numbers in the first array like 1 or 13 so the final out put should be

```
 { '18': { online: true, stest: 56, thnick: 'iiii', userid: 18 } }
```

so i tried to write this code

```
for (var i = 0, len = ol.length; i < len; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0, len2 = ol2.length; j < len2; j++) { 
            //console.log('disnicknames[j].blko',disnicknames[j].blko);
            if (nicknames[i].userid === disnicknames[j].blko) {
                nicknames.splice(j, 1);
                len2=ol2.length;
                //console.log()
                console.log('length1',ol.length);
                console.log('length2',ol2.length);

            }
        }
    }
```

but i get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userid' of undefined

Comment: are you sure that nicknames[i] always exists for every i value? Can you post a console.log of nicknames, disnicknames,  ol and ol2?

Comment: And what is `nicknames` ? Could you show us a full code?

Comment: the output's in the post are the console outputs for nicknames and disnicknames and llength out put for disnicknames output length 2 

and nucknames length are output 3

Comment: nicknames and disnicknames are the array in his question but what are ol and ol2?

Comment: @kikiwie       var kokshh = nicknames;
    var fu = disnicknames;
    var ol = Object.keys(kokshh);
    var ol2 = Object.keys(fu);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are not actually iterating array, but an object. there is no `nicknames[i]` since it doesn't have `index` but a `key`. you have to iterates it through its keys

```
var disnicknames = { '1': { blko: 1 }, '13': { blko: 13 } };
var nicknames = { '1': { online: false, stest: 765767, thnick: 'kjjkjkj', userid: 1 }, '13': { online: false, stest: 87, thnick: 'nnnmm', userid: 13 },'18': { online: true, stest: 56, thnick: 'iiii', userid: 18 } };
for (var key1 in nicknames) {
  if (nicknames.hasOwnProperty(key1)) {
    for (var key2 in disnicknames) {
      if (disnicknames.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
        if (key2 == key1) {
          delete nicknames[key1];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(nicknames);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i would suggest that you do (if you can use underscore.js):

```
_.forEach(nicknames, (value, key) => {
 _.forEach(disnicknames, (val, ke) => {
    if (key === ke) delete nicknames[key]
 })
})
```